# Responsive Sidebars - How can be achieved?

Tags: css, web, responsive-design

I am willing to make something like what [TNW](http://thenextweb.com/) has done. If you see on screen < 900px, it hides side column navigation and shows option to slide down. I know they re using Media Queries but the css looks quite big and complicated to me plus I am not sure whether it is doing all with help of Media query only or browser resize option also being used.

What is the minimilist and easy to achieve this option. My only task is to show this option for screens lesser than 800px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ani is right about a few things. Definitely make sure you have a viewport tag and of course use media queries to control your CSS at various viewport widths.

However, you really don't need the JS they posted. It's also not the best idea to use `.resize`. Instead, use something like [mediaCheck](https://github.com/sparkbox/mediaCheck) which uses [matchMedia](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) under the hood to conditionally execute JS based on media queries. If you must use `.resize` for something use something like [Cowboy's Throttle plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) because each browser handles the `resize` event differently.

A great tutorial on implementing an off-canvas navigation (like TNW) is [over at Smashing Mag](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/15/off-canvas-navigation-for-responsive-website/). Essentially, build your styles up using `min-width` queries (smallest to biggest), and only use JS to manage the state of the navigation at specific breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is css, it's pretty simple:

CSS:

```
sidebar{
  //your css
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
   sidebar{
       your css for 800width
   }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add meta tag:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

If using jquery: This is not preferred but if you don't want to use css then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    responsive();
    $(window).resize(function() { responsive(); });
});

function responsive(){
   var winWidth = $(window).width();
   if(winWidth < 800) { 
       // do stuff here
    }  
    else{
    }
}
```